# Symfony 2.7 cannot use doctrine command

Tags: php, symfony

Ok so this has taken me to a verge...... So i have started new Symfony 2.7 project. I then went on to configurations followed by Database set up and this is where I am struggling every time I type `app/console doctrine` command I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in /Users/Tomazi/Dev/symfony2test/app/autoload.php on line 11
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/Tomazi/Dev/symfony2test/app/console:0
PHP   2. require_once() /Users/Tomazi/Dev/symfony2test/app/console:10
PHP   3. require_once() /Users/Tomazi/Dev/symfony2test/app/bootstrap.php.cache:5

Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in /Users/Tomazi/Dev/symfony2test/app/autoload.php on line 11

Call Stack:
    0.0010     224456   1. {main}() /Users/Tomazi/Dev/symfony2test/app/console:0
    0.0184     406824   2. require_once('/Users/Tomazi/Dev/symfony2test/app/bootstrap.php.cache') /Users/Tomazi/Dev/symfony2test/app/console:10
    0.0187     407592   3. require_once('/Users/Tomazi/Dev/symfony2test/app/autoload.php') /Users/Tomazi/Dev/symfony2test/app/bootstrap.php.cache:5
```

Looking at the error I understand `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry` is missing in app/autoloader.php ?!

autoloader.php:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/**
 * @var ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

In my auto loader the so called missing class is used with its namespac......

What is causing this error any idea...?

Comment: Does the folder "vendor/doctrine" exist? If not, you are probably missing your dependencies, which you need to install first with a 'composer install doctrine/doctrine'

Comment: Yes this folder exiata

Comment: Weird. Does this whole path exists too? "vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php"